# Abstract class type

Tags: c++, juce

I'm trying to initialize a class like this:

```
m_OSCListener = new OSC_Listener(*this, 12345);
```

But the compiler throws "**Allocating an object of abstract class type 'OSC_Listener'**" at me?

The class looks like this:

```
class MainComponent;

class OSC_Listener: public Thread, private MessageListener
{
public:
    OSC_Listener(MainComponent& owner_, int port);
    ~OSC_Listener();

    void handleMessage (const Meddelande& message);
    void run();

private:
    int m_Port;

    ScopedPointer <MemoryBlock>     messageData;
    ScopedPointer <DatagramSocket>  socket;

    MainComponent& owner;

    JUCE_DECLARE_NON_COPYABLE_WITH_LEAK_DETECTOR (OSC_Listener);
};
```

Why is this?

Comment: there might be an abstract method in one of the base classes (or in that macro)

Comment: (Hmmm, I've seen that portrait before here... http://stackoverflow.com/users/85371/sehe)

Comment: @MooingDuck damn it! Gotta change it!;)

Comment: @Daggepagge Are you a sock puppet, or just coincidentally using the same avatar image?!?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Juce::MessageListener has an abstract virtual function you need to override:

http://www.juce.com/api/classMessageListener.html

add this to your class:

```
virtual void handleMessage (const Message &message) {}
```

Comment: Implementing the body of that function is probably _very_ important

Comment: (problem is your handleMessage function uses a different type)

Comment: thank you! I guess that my question is how do I create a subclass of Message then? http://www.juce.com/api/classMessage.html

Comment: Sorry, I don't know enough about JUCE's message dispatch to give you a specific answer.  It really depends on who is dispatching the messages to your listener.  You could use run time type information to decide the the messages arriving are yours or the base class, but I'd look for some more examples before doing that.